# Set Cell Colours in Google Sheet through Script with an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-docs

It's very straight forward to get a sheets cell values into an array. Then you can edit any individual cell or cells you want (In the array). Then write that same array back to the sheet. Like below.

```
var adSpendExprtSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ad Spend Export");
var adSpendExprtSheetData = adSpendExprtSheet.getRange(1 ,1, adSpendExprtSheet.getLastRow(), adSpendExprtSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

Then you can change values in the array just saved.

```
adSpendExprtSheetData[0][0] = "Changing first cell in array"
```

Then we can use this same array. Which we have updated. Passing it back to be written on the actual sheet.

```
adSpendExprtSheet.getRange(1 ,1, adSpendExprtSheet.getLastRow(), adSpendExprtSheet.getLastColumn()).setValues(adSpendExprtSheetData);
```

Can we do this for setting colours?

Right now I would have to get the range of individual cells. Then use setBackground("#00ff00");

Can I put all colour values into an array? Change the colours of cells with a HEX value. Then write that array back to the sheet?

I need to optimize my script. Instead of taking 5 minutes. It could be done in seconds. By reading and writing to the sheet only a few times. Not hundreds.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, how about using `getBackgrounds()` and `setBackgrounds(color)`? In this case, you can use it like `getValues()` and `setValues()` in your question. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var adSpendExprtSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ad Spend Export");
var range = adSpendExprtSheet.getRange(1 ,1, adSpendExprtSheet.getLastRow(), adSpendExprtSheet.getLastColumn());
var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
backgrounds[0][0] = "#FF0000";  // This is red color as a sample.
range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
```

- In this case, the value retrieved with `getBackgrounds()` is 2 dimensional array. And it can be put to the cells using `setBackgrounds()`. By this, I think that the process cost will be able to be reduced than that of `getBackground` and `setBackground`.

#### Note:

- If you want to set one color to the range, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var adSpendExprtSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ad Spend Export");
    var range = adSpendExprtSheet.getRange(1 ,1, adSpendExprtSheet.getLastRow(), adSpendExprtSheet.getLastColumn());
    range.setBackground("#FF0000");
  ```

#### References:

- [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)
- [setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackgrounds(String))

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you! You've filled in any gaps I had :)

Comment: @Jack Trowbridge Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.